# Hard disk faintly clicking now and again, no performance issues to be seen

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My current computer is running on a SSD, and has two HDDs in it which are usually turned off if not in use trough Windows power settings. Every now and then, I hear a very faint click coming from my case, but I haven't ever ran into any noticeable performance issues and every hard drive has very good health.

How can I figure out which drive is clicking? Is there a monitoring software for such a thing?

Comment: Unplug one, see if you hear the clicking, if not replace the other one

Comment: How often is "now and then"? It's fairly normal - HDDs will park heads after some period of inactivity.

Comment: You can try running a SMART reporting tool like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/download/index-e.html) on each drive, and see if any errors are reported.

Comment: This could be nothing more than Windows powering down one of the drives because it's not in use. Edit your current power plan to never power down hard drives, and if the problem goes away you have your answer.

Comment: @Twisty Some ("green") hard drives will park heads even without the OS instructing them to. So it's still a possibility even if changing the power plan does not stop the noise.

Comment: @Bob Good point the OP should take into consideration. He'll know (or be able to find out) if either drive is a low-power "green" model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be nothing more than Windows powering down one of the drives because it's not in use. Edit your current power plan to never power down hard drives, and if the problem goes away you have your answer.

Also, as @Bob noted, some hard drives automatically power down (which necessarily involves parking the heads) after a period of inactivity. This happens independently of any configured power-management settings. Such drives are usually branded "green" or "low-power". If you have such a drive, ensuring it receives some activity every few minutes for long enough to keep it active while you listen for the clicking noise is a good way to determine if this is the source of that sound.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It was in far merely one of the hard drives parking his head after a while. Not sure how that went by me...